# Is it possible to have chemical structure (image) as node property in neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j, rdkit, image-file

I am trying to add images as properties of chemical nodes in Neo4j. What I already know is we can create URLs for each image files and add the URL as a node property. But what I want to know is if I can readily visualize images within neo4j without having to click URLs and getting directed to the location of the file. So ideally, I would have all node properties including chemical structures when I double click a node in Neo4j Bloom ([see attachement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eA3r.png)). I am working with python.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is something that you should do in a visualization layer, at least if the picture below is what you're after.[image]

Disclosure: I work for Graphileon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is this in Neo4j? Is there a documentation where this could have been explained?

Comment: @rkarki  No this is not in Neo4j. It is in our own viz layer. Disclosure: I work for Graphileon.